# The form's view data is expected to be an instance of another class error creating form instance of another entity

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I get the following error when trying to create a form from another entity to pass through to my view.

I have two entities in this context `CourseGuide` and `CourseGuideRow` and I would like to pass through a form view of `CourseGuideRowType` to my view - how can I do this?

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class
>   CRMPicco\CourseBundle\Entity\CourseGuide, but is an instance of class
>   CRMPicco\CourseBundle\Entity\CourseGuideRow. You can avoid this error
>   by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms an instance of class
>   CRMPicco\CourseBundle\Entity\CourseGuideRow to an instance of
>   CRMPicco\CourseBundle\Entity\CourseGuide.

This is my controller:

```
// CourseGuideController.php
public function viewAction(Request $request)
{
    if (!$courseId = $request->get('id')) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('No Course ID provided in ' . __METHOD__);
    }

    $resource = $this->get('crmpicco.repository.course_guide_row')->createNew();
    $form     = $this->getForm($resource);

    // ...

}
```

My Symfony FormBuilder class:

```
// CourseGuideRowType.php
use Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Form\Type\AbstractResourceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class CourseGuideRowType extends AbstractResourceType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('channel', 'crmpicco_channel_choice', array('data_class' => null))
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('courses', 'text')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @return string name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'crmpicco_course_guide_row';
    }
}
```

I have tried the `data_class => null` suggestion mentioned elsewhere, but this has no effect.

If I pass through the data_class like this:

```
$form     = $this->getForm($resource, array('data_class' => 'CRMPicco\CourseBundle\Entity\CourseGuideRow'));
```

I then get this:

> Neither the property "translations" nor one of the methods
>   "getTranslations()", "translations()", "isTranslations()",
>   "hasTranslations()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class
>   "CRMPicco\CourseBundle\Entity\CourseGuideRow".

Why is this? There are translations attached to the `CourseGuide` entity but not the `CourseGuideRow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add this function in your FormType:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'YourBundle\Entity\YourEntity',
    ));
}
```

And don't forget the specific use:

`use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;`

EDIT

In native Symfony (with the Form component):

```
public function showAction()
{
    /.../
    $entity = new YourEntity();
    $form = $this->createForm('name_of_your_form_type', $entity); 

    # And the response:

    return $this->render('your_template.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't have any effect. I'm still seeing the same error.

Comment: is `crmpicco.repository.course_guide_row` the return of getName() method in one of your FormType?

Comment: It's not, but I don't think it should be. I am using Sylius and calling the `getForm` method here https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Controller/ResourceController.php#L411 . I've updated my question with my latest changes and the new error message which makes me think there is something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Actually, I stand corrected - it appears I should be passing the form name through...but to `createForm` instead.

Comment: In native Symfony (with the Form component): `$form = $this->createForm('name_of_your_form_type', the_entity_object);` And the response: `return $this->render('your_template.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);`

Comment: Thanks, feel free to submit that as an answer and i'll more than happily accept. Thanks for your help.